# where is input.h located?

Tags: configuration, files

I can't remember what directory this file is found in off hand.  Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a more precise google search, I found the answer: 
/usr/include/linux/input.h

Answer (score 2):

you can also look in the system using the following command: $ sudo find / -type f -iname input.h; it'll take a while, or $ locate input.h =)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a header file from a dev package that isn't installed, you can use the search from (the non-official site) http://packages.ubuntu.com/ . So for example, you can see all the packages that provide input.h in maverick at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=input.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=maverick .

Alternatively, you can use the archive provided contents file in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/RELEASE/Contents-ARCH.gz , replacing RELEASE with the release (e.g. lucid, maverick) and ARCH (i386, amd64). Within that, you can search for the specific file and get the package from that.

If you know the file came from a package that's currently installed, you can use 'dpkg -S FILE' to find out what package and where the file is located.